# Reducing content indexing impact on SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to answer a question for one of my certification exams which is as follows:

---

You have a SharePoint Server 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1) server farm.

You have a front-end Web server and an application server.

You discover that when the application server indexes content, it takes a long time for the front-end Web server to respond to the user requests.

You need to reduce the number of items that the application server can index simultaneously.

The solution must ensure that all content is indexed.

What should you configure?

A. crawler impact rules
B. crawl rules
C. host distribution rules
D. search scopes

What is the correct answer?

Comment: I have flagged this post for transport to sharepoint.stackexchange.com as that is an appropriate forum for these kinds of questions and will be better answered there.

Comment: I'll happily migrate this to our SharePoint site, but you need to at least demonstrate that you've thought about what the solution might be and why. When you've done that flag for re-open and migration. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The configuring the Crawler Impact rules will allow you to reduce the number of requests made by the application server to the source data (in this instance the web front end).